# Establecer Limite de una cifra determinada en un jtextbox en java

Tags: java

Quiero colocar un limite de 10 en un jtextbox en java pero lo que consigo es tener un limite de 19, yo pregunto por la primera posición de mi cadena, si esta es 1 le otorgo un limite de 2 permitiéndome colocar otra cifra para colocar el 0 y así obtener el 10 pero no se como limitar al usuario a que este coloque solo el 0.
Aquí dejo el código

```
 private void NumeroDeIncognitasKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                            

    char caracter = evt.getKeyChar();
    int limite;
    String cadena = NumeroDeIncognitas.getText() + caracter;
    if ((cadena.charAt(0) == '1')) {
        limite = 2;
    } else {
        limite = 1;
    }
    if (NumeroDeIncognitas.getText().length() == limite) {
        evt.consume();
    }
    if (cadena.charAt(0) == ',') {
        evt.consume();
    } else {
        if (((caracter < '0') || (caracter > '9')) && (caracter != KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)) {
            evt.consume();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: si, lo se pero quiero es que el limite sea de 10, 10 son 2 números y si coloco 1 me permite colocar otro numero y quiero que ese numero solo sea el 0 para tener 10, me explico? @IvanBotero

Comment: Si! Ya comprendi :) Lo siento

Comment: Ya he realizado la prueba, con el codigo que he adjuntado, ha funcionado correctamente

Comment: me ha servido, gracias @IvanBotero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion es que realices la validacion de la longitud del campo *NumeroDeIncognitas* y cuando este tenga la longitud *1* y el *limite* sea *2* entonces validara que no se escriba algo distinto a 0

```
    char caracter = evt.getKeyChar();
    int limite;
    String cadena = NumeroDeIncognitas.getText() + caracter;

    if ((cadena.charAt(0) == '1')) {
        limite = 2;
    } else {
        limite = 1;
    }

    if (NumeroDeIncognitas.getText().length() == limite) {
        evt.consume();
    }

    if (cadena.charAt(0) == ',') {
        evt.consume();
    } else {

     /* Validacion del numero 10*/

        if (limite == 2 && NumeroDeIncognitas.getText().length() == 1) {
            if (caracter != '0') {
                evt.consume();
            }
        }

     /***************************/

        if (((caracter < '0') || (caracter > '9')) && (caracter != KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)) {
            evt.consume();
        }

    }
```